# redirection after signin with the use of cognito user groups

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have setup a cognito user pool with amplify and react. I now want to configure the authentication in such a way that after signin the users are redirected to pages depending on which group they are in meaning if someone from the group "admin" signsin he will be directed to a different page than someone from the group "user". Help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the user `accessToken` after logging in via Amplify Auth, you will be able to get the groups user is assigned to via `accessToken.payload["cognito:groups"]`.

You can also get the user session via `const session = await Auth.currentSession();`, inside you will find the `accessToken`.

Based on that you will be able to redirect wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks alot have been able to solve my problem with this